# Change Android blue color scheme

Tags: android, android-theme, color-scheme

On Android ICS you get the standard blue highlight color for all user controls, you get this on elements like textviews, highlights on buttons, indications on the end of a scrollview and tabwidgets.

Is there a way to change all the color's at once using a theme?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!